# Do I need to fix all 404 in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, 404

We are a software manufacturer with a partner based sales model.

In Google Search Console, we are regularly receiving numerous 404 errors. We are unsure, if we need to fix all of these:

- Some are genuine typos, do we need to fix them
- Some are typos on our partners or directory websites
- Some seem random

Are there Google guidance documents on how which ones of those we need to fix and within what timeframe. Is this dependent on our amount of traffic as well.